# SWIFT - Call a friend to chat

Tags: ios, swift, phone-call

I am a beginner in swift developpment.

I am looking for help to write the swift code that would give a call to a friend of my contact list, and:

- if he answers to my call, it opens a chat window. (no vocal conversation, just chat). At the end of the call, it goes back to the app and the whole conversation is deleted definitly.
- if he doesn't answer, it gives me the possibility to let an alert and when he connects himself to the app, he has a notification that ask him if he wants to call me back.

Here are a few lines, but can't figure out how to go on :

```
var phoneNumber: String = "telprompt://".stringByAppendingString(titleLabel.text!) // titleLabel.text has the phone number.
UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(NSURL(string:phoneNumber)!)
```

Answer (score 1):

What you are planning is as far as I know impossible. The code you wrote only launches the phone app and calls. You won't get any callbacks in your app from the phone app

Comment: Maybe i can just write a function to send alerts to my friend when i want to call him ?